# Can I configure Windows 10 rights so that one user can install programs but not alter passwords?

Tags: windows-10

I would like my kid to be able to install Steam games without me being involved. But I don't want him to be able to do any user editing etc. How can I accomplish this in Windows 10?

I'm the Admin and he needs to stay Standard User but I'd like to give him *some* rights.

Comment: Just create a new user group, inherits the User group, but also has the permissions to install applications.  Just edit the local group policy on the user group